# How to make "if" condition stand for all struct items in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I want to know how to make that "if" condition stand for all struct items in the node. It counts just 1 items and quits the cycle. Here is the code. Im trying to make a function that checks the expiry date on a item in a database. Please disregard the bulgarian text.

```
LIST *sortPr(LIST *pFirst) {

    LIST *b = NULL, *p;

    LIST *b1, *bus1 = NULL;
    int yearcur = 1;
    printf("Vuvedete teku6ta godina");
    scanf("%d", &yearcur);
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        setcolor(COL_RED);
        printf("Списъкът е празен\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(4);
    }
    for (p = pFirst; p != NULL; p = p->pNext)
    {
        if ((yearcur - p->body.year) > p->body.expd)
        {

                b = p;



        }

        b1 = newElement(bus1, b->body);
        return b1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh?  What do you mean, "stand for all struct items?"

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have `return b1` inside your for loop. This would terminate it after the first iteration, and return `b1` out of the function.

```
LIST *sortPr(LIST *pFirst) {
    LIST *b = NULL, *p;
    LIST *b1, *bus1 = NULL;
    ...
    for (p = pFirst; p != NULL; p = p->pNext) {
        ...

        // This would return b1 during the first iteration itself
        return b1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the cause of not having all structure items going through the if statement.